# (Novice) How are limits rigorous?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm new to calculus and I'm confused how limits are rigorous and not just a trick.
For example if you are computing the derivative of $x^3$ at 2
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{(2+dx)^3-(2)^3}{dx} $$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{2^3+3(2)^2dx+3(2)dx^2+dx^3-2^3}{dx} $$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{dx\to 0}\frac{3(2)^2dx+3(2)dx^2+dx^3}{dx} $$
Here we cancel out the dx s which requires dx not to eqaul zero:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{dx\to 0}{3(2)^2+3(2)dx+dx^2} $$
And then remove the terms with dx which requires dx to equal zero:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = {3(2)^2} $$
I don't understand how this makes sense mathematically.

Comment: It makes sense because the computation rules are the result of demonstrations. See [Properties of Limitis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Properties)

Comment: It sounds like you might be interested in the [rigorous $\epsilon,\delta$ definition of limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#(ε,_δ)-definition_of_limit), which is usually not introduced until a more advanced calculus course.

Comment: The formal treatment of limits is covered in all caclulus books, and it would be unrealistic for us to write one chapter worth of detailed explanation on the fly. Refer either to your textbook or to *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin.

Comment: The answer to this question is quite long, but it can be found in any calculus textbook that develops limits rigorously. For one example, you could look at Michael Spivak's *Calculus*. A tip: using $dx$ as your variable for limits will confuse you. Write something like $\lim_{h\to 0}{3(2)^2+3(2)h+h^2}$ instead. You should only use $dx$ in the notation $dy/dx$ (and in the notation for integrals, too).

Comment: Every comment here is relevant and good, but I would like to add that the concept of a limit is the concept of approaching a value. Therefore it is a fundamental misunderstanding of this concept to think about $dx$ as having a fixed value (eg it is equal to or not equal to zero). $dx$ is **approaching** zero, and the removal at the last step (where you say $dx$ equal to zero) is because those terms where $dx$ appears are also **approaching** zero.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio: I agree with the sentiment, but I think Baby Rudin is a very poor choice to learn from at first. It requires much more mathematical maturity to read than, say, Michael Spivak's *Calculus*, or *Understanding Analysis* by Stephen Abbott.

Comment: @Joe In my opinion he should use neither: he should use the one that his course uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that we cancel out $dx$ *under* the limit, and we remove terms with $dx$ *together* with limit ("take the limit").

If you take definition of limit: $A = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)$ iff $\forall \epsilon \exists \delta: 0 < |x| < \delta \rightarrow |A - f(x)| < \epsilon$, you can see that $A = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) \cdot x}{x}$ iff $A = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)$, as $\left|A - \frac{f(x)\cdot x}{x}\right| < \epsilon$ and $|A - f(x)| < \epsilon$ happens simultaneously. Similarly, $A = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)$ iff $A = \lim\limits_{x\to 0} (f(x) + 6x)$, and so on for all standard rules with limit operations.

More intuitively, when we change something under limit sign, this change doesn't need to be correct when $dx = 0$, only when $dx$ is close to zero, but still non-zero. To remove the limit, we do the opposite - we substitute $dx = 0$. If after substitution we have division by $0$, we can't do this substitution (and in general, we can't do it if it will give point of discontinuity in any part of the expression under limit).

Answer (score 1):

While limits are fully rigorous, for some people (like myself), thinking in terms of infinitesimals is more intuitive.  Think of $dx$ being a value that is not zero, but is infinitely small.  $0.\overline{0}1$ (with the zero infinitely repeating).  If $dx$ is not zero, then $\frac{dx}{dx} = 1$.  If $dx$ is infinitesimal, then any finite value (or infinitesimal value) multiplied by $dx$ will also be infinitesimal.  Any infinitesimal value added to a non-infinitesimal value will be infinitely close to the original number.  However, an infinitesimal divided by another infinitesimal *may* (and often does) yield a finite value.

We can imagine a function called std (standard part) which rounds a number to the nearest value that doesn't include infinitesimals.  In this case, the derivative is:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \text{std}\left(\frac{2^3+3(2)^2dx+3(2)dx^2+dx^3-2^3}{dx}\right) \\
= \text{std}\left(\frac{3(2)^2dx+3(2)dx^2+dx^3}{dx}\right) \\
= \text{std}(3(2)^2 + 3(2)dx + dx^2) \\
= 3(2)^2 = 12
$$

So, here, in the last step, since we were left with finite values multiplied by products of infinitesimals, they were infinitely small, and therefore makes the result infinitely close to the first value.  The standard part function then rounds to that value.

Answer (score 1):

Showing that they are actually rigorously defined is, as comments have noted, a bit lengthy, and is best understood by reading and understanding a good text book. But as to the two specific issues you've stated here:

1 - Your concern about "what if $dx$ is zero?" should have been triggered with your very first line, where you wrote

$$\frac{(2+dx)^3-(2)^3}{dx}.$$

This is already undefined when $dx = 0$, and the resolution to this issue is that a general limit only involves the values a function takes on in a neighborhood of a value $a$, i.e. on a set $\{ x \mid  0 \lt |x-a| \lt \varepsilon\}$ for some $\varepsilon$. Notice that we have "greater than zero", not "greater than or equal to zero". So in your limit you only consider values of $dx$ where $0\lt |dx| \lt \varepsilon$. $dx$ is never zero.

2 - "And then remove the terms with dx which requires dx to equal zero". That's not what is happening. We are using the following facts about limits

$$ 
\lim_{a \rightarrow 0} (f(x) + g(x)) = \lim_{a \rightarrow 0} f(x) + \lim_{a \rightarrow 0} g(x)
$$
$$
\lim_{a \rightarrow 0} c\cdot f(x) = c \cdot\lim_{a \rightarrow 0} f(x)
$$
$$
\lim_{a \rightarrow 0} a = 0
$$

(Note: there are some simple conditions that must be met for these to be applicable, but they are met in our case here.)

That last equation, in the form of $\lim_{dx \rightarrow 0} dx = 0$, is what's being used when "we remove the terms with $dx$". But note that that limit follows from the values of $dx$ in a small neighborhood around $0$, not the value *at* $0$.

Stepping back, what you describe is kind of like what happens when I watch a YouTube video where someone cooks something: I think "okay, they fry it for like 10 minutes", I try it, and mine doesn't come out the way theirs did. And that's because they were doing much more than "fry for 10" - they made sure the pan was the right temperature, had enough liquid in it, and were monitoring the food while it was cooking, not just waiting for 10 minutes. But I didn't notice all that.

Similarly, you are watching equations being modified, but the way you're describing the process misses a lot, and it seems a bit bogus to you. But if you can understand the actual reasons for the manipulations you will see that it is rigorous. Admittedly, it's kinda hard, and requires some thought, but asking questions like this is a good way to start.

Comment: Nice analogy with cooking videos. +1

Answer (score 0):

We don’t just remove 6dx + dx^2. We show that it is less than epsilon no matter how small epsilon > 0 is, if we make dx small. For example if we make dx < eps/12 then 6dx < eps/2, and if we make dx less than sqrt(eps/2) then dx^2 < eps/2, and if we make dx less than the smaller of the two, then the sum is less than eps.

And that’s how a limit works: You can make the difference as small as you like if you make dx small.